# Knockoutjs foreach n rows check if dropdown has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have this html markup:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Orders -->
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <select class="form-control"  data-bind="attr: { id: 'prefix_' + $index() }, options: TeacherNames, optionsValue: 'TeacherId', optionsText: 'TeacherName', optionsCaption: 'Choose Teacher', event: { change: $root.teacherChanged }">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href='#' data-bind="click: $root.RequestImage" class="green-btn blue pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span> Download 
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

There will be n number of items in the foreach loop, that will not be known in the moment of development.

What I want to do is when the $root.RequestImage is clicked, the code needs to check if there is selection made in the respected dropdown for that row, if the selection is made then proceed further, otherwise display alert box with 'error' message.

So in the RequestImage that action should happen, this is the RequestImage function currently:

```
self.RequestImage = function () {

};
```

How can I achieve this?

### Update

OrdersVM:

```
var self = this;
self.Orders = ko.observableArray([]);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST", url: "/webservices/InfoWS.asmx/GetOrders",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.d != null) {
      var orderIds = [];
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.d, function (item) {

        item._teacherOrders = ko.observable();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/webservices/InfoWS.asmx/GetTeachersForMyAccount",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: "{'orderId': " + JSON.stringify(item.OrderId) + "}",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
              return item._teacherOrders(data.d);
            }
          },
          error: function (n) {
            alert('Error retrieving teachers for orders, please try again.');
          }
        });

        item.TeacherNames = ko.computed(function () {
          return item._teacherOrders();
        });

        self.Orders.push(item);
        orderIds.push(item.OrderId);

      });
    }
  },
  error: function (data) {
    var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    console.log("error retrieving orders:" + response.Message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the Orders VM so I dont have to make assumptions when writing a solution

Comment: @QBMS pls check if its ok now, thx for helping out!

Comment: Give me a few, working on it

Comment: Thanks for selected the answer that did exactly what my answer did, but with less detail, the guy clearly took my answer from me.  He even used the same variables name?!

Comment: @QBM5, calm down, this is a coincidence. It was also a surprise for me when I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

1. add an observable `selectedTeacher` to every order object
2. add `value: selectedTeacher` to your selects:

   `<select class="form-control"  data-bind="attr: { id: 'prefix_' + $index()    }, options: TeacherNames, optionsValue: 'TeacherId', ..., value: selectedTeacher"></select>`
3. check that observable in your `RequestImage` event

   ```
   if ( !data.selectedTeacher() ) {
           alert('Error: select teacher')
   } else {
           alert('Success')
   }
   ```

A working demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/zxqyokbe/)

Comment: what is data in data.selectedTeacher?

Comment: it's will be the `order` object for that row